# menu_tree_all_data() returns empty arrays for custom menus

Tags: 7

This works.

```
$tree = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu');
```

This doesn't work.

```
$tree = menu_tree_all_data('menu-health-center');
```

Why doesn't `menu_tree_all_data()` work for custom menus?

Comment: $tree = menu_tree_all_data('machine-name-of-menu'); the machine name of menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom menu machine names always have a prefix of "menu-", e.g.:

```
$tree = menu_tree_all_data('menu-custom-menu');
```

Make sure you're using the right machine name. Edit the menu and look at the URL: The last part of it is the machine name for the menu.

Comment: No in my case it is `menu-health-center` but it isn't working and it does have a sub menu

Comment: Works fine for me (just tested the code to make sure), make sure you're using the right machine name. Edit the menu and look at the URL, the last part of it is the machine name for the menu

Comment: Ok thanks. It doesn't work when used as `drush php-script` ... but from within a `preprocess_node` function works.